# how to pass the element name in variable in xpath marklogic?

Tags: xml, xpath, marklogic

My

```
let $doc :=
  <Test>
    <Abc>value of the element</Abc>

  </Test>
```

Code -

```
for $i in $doc
let $x := 'Abc'
return $i/$x
```

result expected 'value of the element'

please help!!

TIA

Comment: is the value Abc expected to be variable, or is it static and always `Abc`? Asking if you need a more dynamic means of matching element names, or if for this particular case you are just trying to figure out how to select the Abc element.

Comment: Element name is dynamic. So I need to read the element name from doc and search based on that element name and it's value.

Answer (score 4):

In your code example, you let the `$x` variable and assigned a string `'Abc'`. If you wanted to use that string to find elements that have that name, you could adjust your XPath to select child elements and then in a predicate filter, test whether the `name()` or `local-name()`. Either can work if you know there are no namespaces and namespace-prefixes to deal with, but probably best to use `local-name()`.

```
$doc/*[local-name()=$x]
```

That would select the `Abc` element, but if you wanted just the value, you could then select the `text()` node

```
for $i in $doc
let $x := 'Abc'
return $i/*[local-name()=$x]/text()
```

or apply the `string()` function:

```
for $i in $doc
let $x := 'Abc'
return $i/*[local-name()=$x]/string()
```

If you know that it will be the `Abc` element, then you can eliminate the `$x` variable:

```
for $i in $doc/Abc
return $i/string()
```

And you could eliminate the for loop completely and just use an XPath statement like this:

```
$doc/Abc/string()
```

Comment: Good answer, +1 from my side!

Comment: Since you are working with XML, and potentially with namespaces as well: you can cast $x to an xs:QName with proper namespace, and compare fn:name value with $x for better matching with unpredictable namespace prefixes.

Comment: Can write the code here, using above doc?

Comment: local-name() eq $x. This did help, but do we have any other way?